# flappy bird doesnt want to flap its wing when i press space for some reason in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i just just started unity and figured to recreate a flappy bird game to understand unity first. at the part where you put the script onto the "player" aka the bird for some reason the inputs doesn't work even though im certain i made no difference with the tutorial guy and my big sis who is also a programmer didnt really see any fault here. i need help or else i cant make further progress here

ight its solved here, apperantly i forgot to make the body type kinematic

link to tutorial video: https://youtu.be/ihvBiJ1oC9U

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 direction;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    public float strength = 5f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            direction = Vector3.up * strength;

//i've also tried Debug.Log and it worked (edit)
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                direction = Vector3.up * strength;
            }
        }

        direction.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += direction * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Time.deltaTime` is likely a very small number and causing your calculations to be very close to 0.  In flappy bird a "flap" would usually cause a fixed amount of upward movement/velocity, independent of the framerate.  Does holding down the spacebar work?

Comment: Also, if you use a RididBody2D, you shouldn't need to deal with gravity yourself.

Comment: And I just remembered, `Input.GetKeyDown` will only be true for one frame.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are following a tutorial and referencing it, please also provide a link. It really helps with helping you.

Comment: i've put the link to the tutorial video im using and also the inputs actually worked bcuz debug log showed up in both of the if statements but flappy bird still doesnt wanna fly. i also tried using Rigidbody still the same, debug.log triggered but no flapping wing

Comment: also idk if this might help you guys but my MonoBehaviour is colorless, its white

Comment: Is the bird affected by gravity or is it just the flappy part that doesnt work?

Comment: the bird is effected by gravity, when i hit start it falls. the part that doesnt work is the flappy part

Comment: Can you remove the gravity and check again if the bird can flap upwards?

Comment: a- it seems like i made a small mistake here, i havent put the rigidbody2D into kinematic. however i would appreciate if someone can explain to me what dynamic, kinematic and static is

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you are only adding the `direction` once, for one single frame as you tap it. As pointed out in the comments, a even a large velocity will not move you very much in a single frame.

Use a `Rigidbody` to handle your physics. You can then add the flap as a force

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float flapStrength = 5f;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // get the rigidbody component
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var flap = new Vector3();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            flap = Vector3.up * strength;

        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                flap = Vector3.up * strength;
            }
        }

        rb.AddForce(flap); // add the input flap as a force
        // rigidbody will automatically apply gravity and movement
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help here. i've change the code into urs. however for some reason the bird still didnt fly. i've add the Rigidbody and test it out by adding a Debug.Log in both of the if statements. when i press space the debug.log did got triggered but the bird still doesn't fly

Comment: You may need to experiment. Set gravity to 0 and try increasing the force. 5N is not very large